# Class 'Zend_Oauth_Consumer' not found

Tags: php, oauth, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am using ZendOAuth to authenticate with an OAuth authentication. I have installed the package and all it dependencies using composer. But when I try to use this code, it can't find the Zend classes.

I use the following example code to test if the OAuth is working:

```
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($this->options);
$token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
echo $token;
```

When I execute the code I get an error telling me that the class `Zend_Oauth_Consumer` could not be found.

I am sure my composer packages are correctly loaded because all other packages work fine.

Can someone tell me if I am forgetting something? Do I need an extra `include` or `use`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such class in the library. I think you mean:

```
$consumer = new \ZendOAuth\Consumer($this->options);
```

Comment: I was using the documentation form Zend, apparently this doesn't work when using only some packages
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

Comment: Well, those docs are for ZF1, you are using ZF2. I don't think there are docs for some of the standalone ZF2 components, unfortunately OAuth is one of these. The ZF1 docs should be mostly correct, it's just the class names you'll need to change to namespaced equivalents (Zend_Oauth -> \ZendOAuth\\)